# Could we reopen this question ("unreasonably severe teacher")?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Could we reopen [Is there anything I can do about an unreasonably severe teacher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115674/is-there-anything-i-can-do-about-an-unreasonably-severe-teacher/)?

According to the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about  "Requirements and expectations of academicians" are specifically on topic. The way I see it, this fits squarely into that category.  It doesn't seem to fit into any of the off-topic categories either (although I realize that doesn't mean specifically that it's on topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just edited out the undergraduate references and hit it with a mod hammer. Seems like a perfectly fine question to me and I am guessing it got closed by the contingent that believes any question asked by an undergraduate is off topic.

Comment: I absolutely agree, in fact I had voted to reopen shortly before your action. Notwithstanding the now-no-longer-new policy about undergraduate questions, we still get questions closed for mentioning the word undergraduate. I propose to make it a taboo word for this site: the u-word!